# Color Chooser Dot Dialogue Android

Tags: android, colors, popup

I have seen a color theme chooser on many different material design apps (including Google's Messaging app) like so:

[image]

I was wondering if this is a custom resource being used or if it is built into Android, and how to create such a menu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Great repo, just what I was looking for
https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/colorpickercollection